# linear regression - at future time points

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-mining, predictive-modeling, linear-regression

I have a dataset of customer transactions containing revenue, customer id, region, product category, product id, support team, date of transaction etc. The data ranges from Jan 2017 to Nov 2nd 2022.

My objective is to try solving this problem using linear regression - To predict the revenue of a customers in the next 3, 6 and 12 months.

While I can use linear regression to predict a continuous output, how can I use the same algo to enforce a time period criteria?

Should I do the below

a) Make data from Jan 2017 to Dec 2020 as training data

b) Make data from Jan 2021 to Dec 2021 as testing data

c) Create two target columns - Rev_3month and Rev_6month. Formula for them is given below

Rev_3month - Jan 2022 rev + Feb 2022 rev + Mar 2022 rev

Rev_6month - Sum of Jan 2022 rev - Jun 2022) rev

So, now should I do build two linear regression models one with rev_3month as label and another with rev_6month as label?

Is this how people do it when they wish to use linear regression to make predictions at different time points?

Comment: The big question is WHY do you feel that you should be using a regression for this problem. Is there a meaningful reason? Also, you have the revenue values in your data, so you can actually calculate the outcome. If you are talking about predicting revenue 6months from now with no intervening revenue data, you would also not have the other variables because they have not yet happened. So, I feel like either something is missing or unclear in the description or this is not the right approach.

Sample data, the output of a data frame, would be helpful

Comment: @sconfluentus - Thanks for your response. I thought regression can be used for predicting continous values. I just wanted to see whether we can bring prediction at different time points to it. I have revenue data of the PAST 5 YEARS with uneven intervals for different customers. Meaning, not all customers were with us for 5 years. Some were with us for 5 years, some for 2 years and some for 1 year. And in those customers, some did weekly transactions, some bought from us daily and some bought from us only every 6 months. So, what algo do you think I can use for this problem?

Comment: Yes, my objective is to predict the revenue value (6 months from now). we don't have the future data with us. So, we wish to predict (based on past data of 5 years whichever WE HAVE).

Comment: Put it simply, let's say I have data from Jan 2021 to Jun 2022. Now I wish to predict what will be the total revenue that we can expect from this customer from July 2022 to Dec 2022.. So, we make use of data from Jan 2021 to Jun 2022 to come up with features etc...Any other alternate solutions are welcome

Comment: So, this is not a great situation for a linear regression because of the far future prediction window. It may be possible if the prior time values are in some way correlated with future performance. That having been said, I think it will struggle.

Comment: However, Vector Auto Regression is a time-series expansion of the straight up linear regression. It might work, but you will need to address missingness somehow and establish regular intervals to make it work:
https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/11/11.2

Comment: @sconfluentus - Let's say if i prepare/arrange/aggregate my input data (of 5 years) at a sampling freq of 3 month interval, then whatever revenue output that i predict is understood to be for 3 month interval (because input data is arranged like that). Am i right?

Comment: so, linear regression could be used in tgis scenario. AM i right?

Comment: I think using 1-quarter (3-months) is a possible way of handling and managing data with a lot of gaps. Aggregating will cost you some predictive power. Can you use it in a linear regression, there is nothing stoping it. But I do not see it performing well. You could take that same aggregate data and put it into a VAR and it is far more likely to work.

Comment: @sconfluentus - yes, agree. I am going to try a lot of regression models...one of them is linear regression. Just wanted to know whether linear regression can work for these type of scenarios

Comment: The model will run. I doubt it will be useful.

Comment: @sconfluentus - I will also try VAR as per your suggestion. Do you think we should frame this problem as a timseries forecast rather than regression problem? If yes, then I have around 2K customers. Should I build 2k timeseries models then as I want to predict revenue for each customer in the next 6, 9 or n months? Moreover if time series, then the data is at uneven/irregular intervals. Some customers buy every 2 months, some buy every 4 months, some buy only once a year. How do we handle this challenge?

Comment: While I did aggregate the data to 3 month interval but just trying to understand how will this scenario 2000 customers can be handled?

Comment: I think for a global forecast the time series is a great way of handling this. As for individual customers, it my or may not be the way to go. If you can come up with an aggregation Schema which proves consistently predictive across a wide variety of customer types and is easy to 'functionalize' It might make sense to do it or it may require a different model than the general forecast.

Comment: @sconfluentus - what are other models than general forecast models? Would be grateful for your help

Comment: I came across something tweedie regression. Based on your experience, do you think this could be a good candidate for this problem? Or you mean to say this problem should only be framed as time series and not as regression?

Comment: I would say if you frame it as a regression it needs to be one that is time aware, like a Vector Auto Regression (VAR). I think the tweedie will not solve the problem because it allows for the exploration of a bunch of different distributions, but none of them are specifically forward-looking